# Tkinter: why does my image display when I place it on a Tk object but not on a Frame object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is my entire code:

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import screen  # my own local module

window = tkinter.Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(window, width=1920, height=1080)

image = screen.get_photoimage("img/background.png", contain_size=(1920, 1080))
label = tkinter.Label(frame, image=image)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

`screen.get_photoimage()` just creates a `PhotoImage` contained to the given dimensions.

When I run it, it just displays an all-grey window instead of my image. However, when I write:

```py
import tkinter
import screen  # my own local module

window = tkinter.Tk()

image = screen.get_photoimage("img/background.png", contain_size=(1920, 1080))
label = tkinter.Label(window, image=image)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

window.mainloop()
```

It does display my image.

So I can see my image when I place the `Label` it's on onto a `Tk` object but not when I place it onto a `Frame` object. I'm really confused as to why this is.

I don't mind placing it onto some parent other than a `Frame`. The reason why I can't place it directly onto a `Tk` is because it's for a bigger project where I would like to be able to destroy the `Frame` that contains the image (and will also contain some other things) while keeping the window open; if I ran `destroy()` on the `Tk` object that would close the window. So if it's something to do with the `Frame` class itself, I'm happy to swap it out for e.g. a `Canvas` or something if someone knows a class that would work, but putting it directly onto the `Tk` object is not feasible for me. Thanks!

Comment: You never called `.pack()`/`.grid()`/`.place()` on the Frame, so it was never made visible.

Comment: You never call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to call `pack`/`grid`/`place` on the frame—now works as expected